# What kind of image should be used in a web page?

Tags: web-development, websites, image

I have a site that will have lots of images of large size. What is the best format that I should choose for displaying these images?

I need the website to load fast. I am jumbled with different formats of images like jpeg, png, gif, bmp, etc. Which to use in this case and why ?

Comment: Flagged as off topic.  Belongs on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ (though it is probably a duplicate, there)

Answer (score 16):

Use JPEG for images with gradients (like photographs) and PNGs for images with flat colors and straight lines (like screenshots). Use GIF only if you need animations for some reason. Don't use BMP.

JPEG is lossy, so you get artifacts if you try to use it on screenshots.

PNG is lossless, so it looks great with screenshots, but the filesizes get really big for photographs.

GIF is kind of obsolete, PNG is better.

BMP is not a standard web image format.

Comment: This is straight up the correct answer.  I will note that you can often make PNGs even smaller using PNG compression utilities, assuming your program for creating PNG files does a poor job with compression...which is often the case.  Note also that GIF does not support 32bit images; if your GIFs are smaller than your PNGs, it is usually because you are using 16bit gifs and 32bit PNGs.

Answer (score 2):

**In short,** consider **small thumbnail images** as .png formatted wherever you list them in list. And spend some time on **caching** and its configurations.

In combination with this thumbnail images, have your large-sized images as png/jpeg. Generically speaking displaying list of all full-sized images will slow down your page load time.

However, having a wise caching configuration of the static web content through web-server is very important for performance, and it is a good way to go.

Comment: If you're after performance, try to avoid having too many small images, regardless of format. Read up on [sprites](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites).

Answer (score 2):

If your aim is as you say to for "the web-site to load faster" then you might also want to look at making the images available via a Content Delivery Network (CDN) like Amazon Cloud Front or Max CDN.